# To number от varchar2 при неизвестных заранее nls

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть `Oracle 11`.
В строковой колонке(`varchar2`) хранятся числа. Разделителем может быть как точка, так и запятая. Необходимо преобразовать их к числам. Маска числа и настройки `NLS` сессии заранее не известны. Как сделать так, чтобы преобразование всегда отрабатывало без ошибок?

Пока мои мысли движутся в таком направлении:

На первом шаге можно все запятые заменить на точки с помощью `replace`. 
Чтобы на следующем шаге в `to_number` указать `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` обязательно надо указать маску числа. Не понятно как быть, если у меня может быть число как с максимальным количеством знаков до запятой, так и с максимальным количеством знаков после.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока в голову приходит только привести разделитель к текущему для сессии:

```
select TO_NUMBER(
        TRANSLATE('123.456',
                  '.,',
                  (select rtrim(VALUE)||VALUE
                     from NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
                    where PARAMETER='NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS'
                  )
        ))
  from DUAL
```